# Windows 10: Menu Alignment

Tags: windows-10, alignment, app-menu

In recent Windows 10 versions, "Tablet PC Settings" -> Left/Right Handed ( Run -> shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E} ) seems to affect only the context-menu.

How can I change applications' *main menu* default alignment?

Comment: How can I change applications' main menu default alignment? .......   From what to what?

Comment: From left to right and vice versa.

Comment: I look in the Task Bar settings and I am pretty sure you cannot do what you want.

Comment: I'm referring to "Tablet PC Settings" -> Other -> Left/Right Handed.

Comment: I looked in the tablet setup and do not see what you want.

Comment: Please see https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/68038-set-menus-open-aligned-left-right-windows-10-a.html#post2247421.

Comment: I did read through but I was no farther ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.